# how to initialize a PHP bidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Let's say I would like to manage a multidimensional array like (pseudo-code):

```
Array $colors
* wine,red
* cheese,yellow
* apple, green
* pear,brown
```

What code could be used to avoid the following notation, to initialize the array (assuming there will be a hard-coded list of elements=?:

```
$colors[x][y] = 'something';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array(
   array('wine', 'red'),
   array('cheese', 'yellow'),
   array('apple', 'green'),
   array('pear', 'brown')
);
```

***UPD:***

```
foreach ($array as $v) {
   echo $v[0]; // wine, cheese...
   echo $v[1]; // red, yellow...
}
```

Comment: Alexander I need to access both items from each element... 
By coding $array['wine'] it would be possible to access 'red'.... how would you access 'wine', in a foreach loop?

Comment: foreach($array as $item){echo $item} will return red yellow green brown..... how about returning also whine, cheese, apple & pear?

Comment: `foreach($array AS $left => $right) echo $left . ' - ' . $right`

Comment: Alexander, thanks! faileN syntax seems smarter! Kudos to everyone

Comment: This was my original answer, but then I changed it =(

Comment: I had no intention to steal anything, of anybody :P

Comment: @Alex please add an explanation to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want an associative array as your question doesn't mention it.

This is the elegant syntax PHP makes available:

```
<?php
$colors = array(array("wine","red"),
                array("cheese","yellow"),
                array("apple", "green"),
                array("pear", "brown"));

print_r($arr); // Prints out an array as shown in output
?>
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => wine
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cheese
            [1] => yellow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => green
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => pear
            [1] => brown
        )

)
```

To loop over access all the 0's:

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($colors); $x++){
    echo $colors[$x][0];
}
```

Alternatively

```
for($colors as $couple){
   echo $couple[0];
}
```

---

EDIT: It seems like you actually could be better of with an associative though..

```
$colors = array("wine"   => "red",
                "cheese" => "yellow",
                "apple"  => "green",
                "pear"   => "brown");
```

Cause you can still access the keys, as such:

```
 for($colors as $key => $value){
       echo $key . " is " . $value;
    }
```

Comment: Nice sample, it shows how to initialize the array, however I'm still missing how to access the "left column" in a foreach loop, once the array has been initialized...

Comment: I hoped I could avoid the for loop and just use the foreach... Good anyhow! Thanks – Riccardo 0 secs ago

Comment: Added some more, you can access key using associative arrays, as shown.

Comment: I gave the accepted answer to Plutov and faileN just because they have answered before you did complete your answer, although your answer seems more detailed... thanks! :-)

Comment: If the "consumables" data is unique by your business logic, then this answer's associative array will be ideal and most streamlined.  If you expect  to have wine which occurs as "red" and as "white", then you will need another data structure because arrays may not have duplicate keys on this same level.  @Riccardo For the record, the green tick is not necessarily to be awarded to the FASTEST answer but the MOST APPROPRIATE/HELPFUL answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php ;)

Comment: Link-only "hints" can be posted as comments under the question.